# The file system is full.. SQLCODE=-968, SQLSTATE=57011, DRIVER=4.18.60

Tags: memory, db2, filesystems

When I try to run a long query in DB2, I am getting the below error:

> "The file system is full SQLCODE=-968, SQLSTATE=57011,
>   DRIVER=4.18.60"

There is lots of memory available in C drive. So memory is not an issue.

There are 65 table spaces available in the database.

It works fine for other smaller queries but for one long query, I am getting this message repeatedly in DB2.

I have tried multiple solutions but with no luck.

Please help to fix this issue.

Comment: What is your setting for temporary data?

Comment: Please let me know how to check the setting for temporary data?

Comment: Check the db2diag.log file for details

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue. The issue was that the DB was installed in D drive and there was not enough space in it for larger queries to be executed. When the drive space was increased, the error was gone.

Thanks all for your suggestions.